# When to use attributes instead of a list for an S3 class

Tags: r, gt

Writing an S3 class based on a dataframe I am facing the design decision whether to structure the new object as a list (of which the dataframe would be one element) or a dataframe with attributes. My questions are twofold:

1. Are both approaches equally capable?
2. When would you use a list, rather than augmenting the "base object" with attributes?

Regarding the latter question, the only guidance I could find comes from [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html):

> Two basic ways to create an object in S3: with a list or with attributes. With attributes is best if your object behaves like a vector, list if you’re starting from scratch.

I currently lean towards the approach using attributes because it allows the user to handle the new S3 object the same way as the underlying "base object", e.g. in a pipe.

To give an existing example: the table formatting package gt uses a list of which the first element `_data` is the dataframe the table is based on:

```r
gt::gt(mtcars) |> 
  unclass() |> 
  lobstr::tree(max_depth = 1, max_length = 10)
#> <list>
#> ├─_data: S3<tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>...
#> ├─_boxhead: S3<tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>...
#> ├─_stub_df: S3<tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>...
#> ├─_row_groups<chr [0]>: ""
#> ├─_heading: <list>...
#> ├─_spanners: S3<tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>...
#> ├─_stubhead: <list>
#> │ └─label: <NULL>
#> ├─_footnotes: S3<tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>...
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As an alternative approach using attributes, I could see something like this:

```r
structure(
  df, 
  "_boxhead" = tibble(),
  ...
  "class" = "my_new_S3_class"
)
```

Comment: You can sub-class like package `tibble` does. This is basically to extend an attribute, `iris |> tibble::as.tibble() |> class()` returns `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`. Like this you can have the new havior and call `NextMethod` to also have the `"data.frame"` method and behavior.

Comment: Good point! That means I would have to write custom methods though if I use a list, right? For example `print(my_new_s3_object)` could not fall back on the print method for a tibble or dataframe because the actual dataframe is tucked away as a list element.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new class, you can extend class `"list"` or class `"data.frame"` by sub-classing like function `as_myobject` below. A print method for the new object is also included. It calls `NextMethod` to have the expected behavior for data.frames also work for the new class.

```r
print.myobject <- function(x, ...) {
  NextMethod(...)
  num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  chr <- sum(sapply(x, is.character))
  fac <- sum(sapply(x, is.factor))
  if(any(num) || chr > 0L || fac > 0L) {
    cat("---\n")
    if(any(num)) {
      cat(sum(num), "numeric columns with means\n")
      cmeans <- colMeans(x[num])
      print(cmeans)
      cat("\n")
    }
    if(chr > 0L) cat(chr, "character columns\n")
    if(fac > 0L) cat(fac, "factor columns\n")
    cat("---\n")
  }
  invisible(x)
}
as_myobject <- function(x) {
  old_class <- class(x)
  class(x) <- c("myobject", old_class)
  x
}
is_myobject <- function(x) inherits(x, "myobject")

mo1 <- head(iris)
mo1 <- as_myobject(mo1)
is_myobject(mo1)
#> [1] TRUE

# autoprint defaults to  on
mo1
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> ---
#> 4 numeric columns with means
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#>    4.9500000    3.3833333    1.4500000    0.2333333 
#> 
#> 1 factor columns
#> ---

# pass other arguments to 'print'
print(head(mo1), digits = 1)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1            5           4            1         0.2  setosa
#> 2            5           3            1         0.2  setosa
#> 3            5           3            1         0.2  setosa
#> 4            5           3            2         0.2  setosa
#> 5            5           4            1         0.2  setosa
#> 6            5           4            2         0.4  setosa
#> ---
#> 4 numeric columns with means
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#>    4.9500000    3.3833333    1.4500000    0.2333333 
#> 
#> 1 factor columns
#> ---
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>